# Remove Text Conditionally

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to remove the Additional Features text located on the [single listings page](https://my.studiopress.com/themes/agentpress/#demo-full) when no additional features are added?
[image]

This is the PHP from the AgentPress Listings plugin which generates the text:

```
$output .= sprintf( '<p><b>%s</b><br /> %s</p></div>', __( 'Additional Features:', 'agentpress-listings' ), get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'features', '', ', ', '' ) );
```

This is the HTML output

```
<b>Additional Features:</b>
```

This is generated by a plugin which doesn't include a filter however i prefer not to modify the default code in the plugin and are therefore forced to use jQuery or possibly CSS.

Comment: have you tried something like `$('b:contains("Additional Features:")').remove()` ?

Comment: He wants to remove it conditionally though, this would remove the element  without regard of the contents of `agentpress-listings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the siblings size and then remove `Additional Features` check dynamically as follows:

```
if(jQuery(".property-details > .clear").find("p > b").siblings().size() > 1){
     jQuery(".property-details > .clear b").remove();
}
```

I mentioned `jQuery(".property-details > .clear").find("p > b").siblings().size() > 1` because `<br/>` element is rendered in both the cases.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Does work, my bad. thanks a lot. I gave you the big 25!

Answer (score 1):

As per your code it look like you are using `wordpress`. You directly use following php code for this..

```
<?php 
    if(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'features', '', ', ', '' )) {
        $output .= sprintf( '<p><b>%s</b><br /> %s</p></div>', __( 'Additional Features:', 'agentpress-listings' ), get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'features', '', ', ', '' ) );
    }
?>
```

> As we can see your listing items are come in `a` tag, using `jquery` you can check it exist or not

```
if(!$(".property-details > .clear p a").length){
    $(".property-details > .clear p").remove();
}
```

Comment: Can't, its from a plugin with no filter

Comment: Also tested this jQuery solution and it works. Thanks.